# Is there a way to configure heap memory in grails fork mode for test-app via environment variable/config file?

Tags: grails

We are currently finding a way to increase test execution on our CI.

One way we plan to do it is to increase memory for the test-app command.

But we want to do it without increasing memory usage for all of our developers, so we want them to be configurable per machine. Ideally via environment variable or a config file.

We tried adding:

```
test: [maxMemory: System.env.TEST_MEMORY, minMemory: 1664, debug: false, maxPerm: 512, daemon:true]
```

But it does not work.